# Finding the longest sequence on a board?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I need a function that does the following:

As input, it takes a n by n board, on which each spot is either empty, has a black stone or a white stone, and a position.

As output, it returns the length of the longest sequence from the given position. If the position is empty, it returns 0.

For example, if this board was inputted.

```
BUUUU
WWWB
UUUUU
```

where B is a black stone, W is a white stone and U is an empty spot, and the position inputted was (1,0), the output would 3.

Or if this board was inputted:

```
BUUU
WUUU
BUUU
BUUU
```

and the position was 0,3 the output would be zero, since the position is empty. If the position was 3,0 the output would be 2 because of the black column.

Sequences can be horizontal, vertical or diagonal.

This is what I have so far:

If I'm given a position, I loop up, down, both sides, and both diagonals. I keep lopping until I find the sequence breaks, and then return the longest sequence. For example, if this is the board:

```
WUU
WWU
WUU
```

and the position was 1,0. I would loop sideways and find that the longest horizontal sequence is 1, loop diagonally, find the longest sequence is 1 and then loop vertically and find the longest sequence is 3, and therefore return 3.

How can I do this faster? This function needs to be called around 10 million times in one second. My current function can execute around 8 million times per second.

Comment: What have you attempted to try and solve this?

Comment: "My current function" should probably be posted in the question so we can help more directly.

Comment: @mccainz I explained above.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Sorry, I'm not allowed to post my current function. My description should give a good idea of how my function works though.

Comment: You've described the answer I would give you. You may not have implemented it in the most efficient way but without your code, we'd have to write the whole thing from scratch and I'm not sure how many people would want to do that for you.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I'm not really looking for a new implementation of my existing code. I can vouch for its efficiency. I'm looking for a completely new approach to the problem. Something to do with bitmaps maybe, since their used a lot in chess.

Comment: When I asked, "What have you attempted to try and solve this?" I meant where is your code for this problem. Asking for a complete solution is a bit frowned upon, especially without a demonstrated effort to solve on ones own.

Comment: An increase in performance of 25% (as in from 8 to 10 foobars/s) can usually easily be made without a change in algorithm. Very easily. In particular, more clever algorithms usually run slower on small problems than dumb ones.

Comment: This seems like it might be a function that would get called on every square in the board in quick succession. Is that true? If so, you might be able to pretty substantially improve the efficiency by using dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is an O(n^2) operation. Iterate over the board in row-major order. For each position on the board, maintain a 3-tuple count of the longest contiguous sequences using each direction (horizontal, vertical, and diagonal.) When you encounter an occupied position, check all adjacent positions for contiguous sequences, and increment the max length by one should this position be a valid addition to said sequence. Best of luck.